# How to cd into my local git repo from an AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, git

I am running a Mac using OSX Yosemite v10.10.5.

I want to push my local git repo to my remote using AppleScript.

So the git code would be:

shell

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/my-project.git
git push -u origin master
```

But in order to run this from the terminal, first I need to `cd` into my local directory.

```
cd my-directory
```

So how would I do all this from an AppleScript? Or the JavaScript option in the Script Editor would also help.

Comment: Why AppleScript and not just a simple shell script?

Comment: @patrix: Because I will be automating it using Automator. And from what I know, Automator can only run AppleScript (and maybe JavaScript too). But not shell script. But, I will take answers about shell script too. If anyone has one. It's possible I could figure out the AppleScript from the Shell script as a starting point.

Comment: Even with Automator it might be easier to just include a "Run shell script" action and run the lines from above (including the `cd`) from there.

Comment: @patrix: Yes, I just tried that approach. And got an error in the line after the `cd` command. So I don't think the `cd` works from shell? Maybe shell has a different means of accessing the command space inside the directory?

Comment: Most probably the working directory of your Automator action is not what you expect it to be. Try `cd /full/path/to/my-directory` instead. If it doesn't help, please ask a new question showing both the relevant part of the Automator action and the error you are getting

Comment: @patrix: Your answer worked. The system will let me accept it in two minutes time from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can use

```
do shell script "cd my-directory && git init"
do shell script "cd my-directory && git add README.md"
...
```

Comment: Oooohhhhh. Yeah. I didn't think of the `&&`. I was doing it as a separate line. Let me try that approach. Thanks.